# Как просмотреть числа в текстовом файле (pascal)?

Tags: pascalabc.net

Записал числа в файл:

```
var 
    f: file of integer;
    sym, i: integer;
begin
    assign(f, 'C:\Users\HOMe\Desktop\Pascal\numbers.txt');
    rewrite(f);
    for i := 1 to 10 do
    begin
        read(sym);
        write(f, sym);
    end;
    close(f);
end.
```

Теперь хочу просмотреть их в файле, но, естественно, с помощью текстового редактора (блокнота,к примеру) этого не сделать.

Как можно увидеть введенные в текстовый файл числа?

Comment: Операция противоположная `Rewrite` - `Reset`, a противоположная `Write` - `Read`.

Comment: Я подправил Вашу структуру кода. В дальнейшем старайтесь соблюдать её.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно разобраться с таким понятием как бинарные файлы. В данном случае работаете Вы именно с ними. Вы же хотите увидеть текст, т.е. символы. Приведу пример.

Все символы имеют свой код. Так, когда Вы записываете числа в файл, происходит запись кодов, который соответствуют некоторым символам. Таблицу символов можно глянуть [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_ASCII_.D0.B2_.D0.AD.D0.92.D0.9C). Например, если Вы введёте с клавиатуры число 0, то в файл запишется `NUL`, если это будет 80, то запишется `0`. 90 -- `*` и т.д. Всё это можно отследить по таблице, которую я привёл выше. Замечу, что там все коды указаны в 16-ой системе.